# Approve/Reject a task from a custom InfoPath form?

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath, tasks

We are using the OOTB Approval workflow for some tasks that is kicked off when a user enters info on a custom InfoPath form and clicks submit. The user receives the OOTB email with instructions to

1. Review the task
2. Perform the activities for the task and then
3. Use the Open this Task button within Outlook to approve/reject the task.

When the user clicks to review the task, it opens our InfoPath form that was used to create the item so they can review it. Here, I would like to add buttons for Approving and Rejecting the item so that the user does not have to go back into Outlook and use the Open Task option.

I have looked at the OOTB InfoPath form that Outlook opens with approve/reject and tried something similar and I cannot seem to recreate them. I have tried adding fields with the correct default values (Status, TaskStatus, Completed, PercentComplete) and then submitting the form to the host (similar to what the OOTB task approval seems to do) but this doesn't have any affect...the task still remains In Progress.

How can I add Approve/Reject buttons to my InfoPath form that will approve/reject an OOTB workflow task?